# Jquery ajax call gives parsererror

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
function LoadUsers() {
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "../../UserService2.asmx/GetUsers",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json"
            });


            request.done(function (msg) {
            });


            request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            });
        }
```

I am getting a 200 OK but parsererror

Comment: Chances are your web service is returning invalid JSON, then.

Comment: You've got two `dataType` in ajax options

Comment: @cy3er, the case is not the same, though, so they're not duplicate keys. Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: I still have the error after removing datatype duplicate.
I am getting responseText as offending url

Comment: Can you check your json response in [jsonlint](http://pro.jsonlint.org/)

Comment: I don't know how to use jsonlint

Comment: paste your JSON response here

Comment: It doesn't enter the webservice method at all

Comment: Here is what is happening. I have renamed the Service to UserServices and when I browse to this service I get the following exception - Offending URL: http://localhost:26044/UserServices.asmx
Source: System.Web
Message: Could not create type 'Friendisc.WebService'.

I have created a new webservice and browsing on that webservice doesn't show any webmethod

Comment: Solved! There was an error from my webservice name